# How can I extract points from image file using R?

Tags: r, image, graph, extract

I am trying to extract points from scanned image file from printed book. The image is quite clear.

Does anyone can help me?

Comment: People here are more than willing to help here.. IF you frame the question better.  What format is your image? What is the context of your problem? Look at the questions already asked and answered that relate to your problem.

Comment: This is a coding and data oriented website. You have provided neither.

Comment: Are you looking for a [plot digitizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converting_scanned_graphs_to_data)?

Answer (score 3):

In R you can use the digitize package.

The full explanations are [here](http://lukemiller.org/index.php/2011/06/digitizing-data-from-old-plots-using-digitize/) and [there](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Poisot.pdf) and.. well [google](http://www.google.com/) has lots more.

Comment: But it's much faster and easier, as V Zoonekynd suggested, to use EngaugeDigitizer or DataThief.  These are specialized tools which are very good at extracting data from an image.